# Import large database faster

Tags: mysql, import, processlist, dbimport

I'm currently importing a large database: 8GB and the largest table has 40 millions row.

The import is taking for hours.

I'm importing using the following command: `mysql -u root -p db < db.qsl`

When I do: `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` There is only in query.

Is there any way to be more efficient and to do way more insert in the same time ?

(I'm running on a 16GB ram server and I've now idea what I should provide)

Comment: How are you doing the import?

Comment: If your using mysql dump, memory is usually the biggest bottleneck. But it depends if your doing it locally, or through some sort of program like phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You had better use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/). This is a very efficient software to import data - size is not a concern.